# Android SharedPreferences to getInt

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreferences` to get the "age" but encounters the following error...how could this be handled?? Thanks!

```
SharedPreferences settings3 = Profile.this.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",0);
age = settings3.getInt("age",25);
textview_age_input.setText(""+age);  //LINE 122
```

## Logcat:

```
08-24 01:23:59.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15117): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa0
08-24 01:23:59.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15117):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
08-24 01:23:59.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15117):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3806)
08-24 01:23:59.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15117):    at com.abc.abc.Profile.onCreate(Profile.java:122)
08-24 01:23:59.588: E/AndroidRuntime(15117):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
```

Comment: That should work. What happens if you do `textview_age_input.setText(String.valueOf(age));`?

Comment: I have tried that too! It reports the same error.. I have also cleaned the Project

Comment: strange but that I have tried agee = settings3.getInt("age",25); then it works...!!

Comment: You are getting a Resources not found exception.  You can surround your code with a TRY/CATCH to be sure that this is the offending code.  My guess is that age is not getting written correctly.  Can you show us the code where you set the age?

Comment: Can you show where you setting id of "textview_age_input" .

Comment: I dont know why changing the age = settings3.getInt("age",25); to become agee = settings3.getInt("age",25); would make it works...Will it matter if the variable and the name of the key are the same??

Comment: can you plese post your activity code and related xml code ??

Comment: Think there's nothing wrong with SharedPreferences, its something related to resource, as the logcat suggests.